# Get the rest of the string after occurrence of particular letters

Tags: c#

```
string ABC = "This is test AZ12346";
```

Need value that occurs *after* `AZ`. `AZ` will *always be present* in the string and it will always be the *last word*. But number of characters after AZ will vary.

Output should be : `AZ123456`

Comment: And what have you tried? This could be very simple with both RegEx and indexOf + substring

Comment: _"Need value that occurs after AZ"_  .... _"Output should be : AZ123456"_

Comment: `ABC.Split(new [] { "AZ" }, StringSplitOptions.Remove)[1]` ^_^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and familiarize yourself with [ask] (preferably with a [mcve]). Your question as it is now will likely receive down-votes due to an apparent [lack of effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt) and what seems to be contradictions in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LastIndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
string ABC = "This is test AZ12346";
string delimiter = "AZ";

// "AZ123456"
string result = ABC.Substring(ABC.LastIndexOf(delimiter));
```

In case `delimiter` can be abscent

```
int p = ABC.LastIndexOf(delimiter);

string result = p >= 0
  ? ABC.Substring(p)
  : result; // No delimiter found
```

If you are looking for *whole word* which starts from `AZ` (e.g. `"AZ123"`, but not `"123DCAZDE456"` - `AZ` in the middle of the word) you can try *regular expressions*

```
 var result = Regex
   .Match(ABC, @"\bAZ[A-Za-z0-9]+\b", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
   .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
ABC.Substring(ABC.LastIndexOf("AZ"));
```